# jQuery: Finding a particular HREF Link

Tags: jquery, href

Basically the idea is to find out what the current location is of the document and change the class of the link (navigation accordion) to be changed. So far I have this below it works if the pageURL (variable) is the actual link but I do not want to create a whole list of possible links hence the $(location).att('href');

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var pageURL = $(location).attr('href');
    $('a[href=pageURL]').attr('class', 'active');
});
```

Any help from any one would be greatly appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: Note that this requires you to use absolute URLs as `href` values.

Comment: @Gumbo: actually jQuery works around that one now, so you shouldn't use absolutised values. It has to do this for consistency with browsers' native `querySelectorAll` implementations which will be used where available. I would still recommend using a class or id in preference to relying on an exactly link address though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to concatenate the variable into the selector string.

```
$('a[href=' + pageURL + ']').attr('class', 'active'); });
```

The way you had it, "pageURL" was simply *part* of the selector, so jQuery was looking for `<a>` elements with "pageURL" for the href attribute.

Also, I don't know what the `location` variable represents, but if you're looking for the current window location, you need a different approach.

Comment: thank you patrick I am currently using the variable as the links at the moment may need the entire path (http://) which the window.location in javascript fails to put into it

Comment: @NWhite - I thought `window.location` gave you the `http://` in all browsers. Anyway, if not, just test for it and append it if necessary. I'll update my answer.

Comment: sorry my fault window.location does I was using location.pathname from Slaks answer oops

Comment: @NWhite: You should use `[href*=...]`.

Comment: ah ok sorry I didn't notice the * in your answer thanks SLaks as well

Answer (score 4):

By writing `'a[href=pageURL]'`, you are searching for `a` elements with `href` attributes equal to the literal `pageURL`, not the contents of the variable.
Instead, you need to concatenate the contents of the variable into the selector string.

For example:

```
$('a[href*="' + location.pathname + '"]').attr('class', 'active');
```

There's no point in using jQuery to access `location.href`.
Writing `location.pathname` will make it work even if the link doesn't include a domain name.
Using the `[href`**`*`**`=...]` selector matches elements with `href` attributes that *contain* the string.

Comment: Just like `/foo/bar` contains `/foo`.

Comment: @Gumbo: If that is an issue, you can change it to `href$=`, which checks that it ends with that path.   However, that won't handle querystrings.

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax is:

```
$('a[href=' + pageURL + ']').attr('class', 'active'); });
```